# Authentication in front of Cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, authentication, cassandra, ldap

We have a cluster of Cassandra instances (AWS). Right now, any users with IAM privilege to connect to those instances can run `csql` shell, commands etc to do what they need off of the default Cassandra user.

I have a project to now add an authentication layer. The thinking is that while users privileges are limited on the AWS side, they are all using a single Cassandra user to do whatever they need to. This is not auditable and whatsmore, not all of those users should have access to do everything (admin vs read only, etc). We would like them using their Azure (what we use for internal authentication in our company) accounts. So we need to:

- Add authentication
- For each user, have their own user in Cassandra
- Each user will have a role (be part of a group)
- Automatically activate/deactivate the users from their Azure identities.

Built in authentication classes are: `AllowAllAuthenticator` and `PasswordAuthenticator` but these won't work. I think this open source authenticator by instaclustr may work: https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/apache-cassandra-ldap-authentication/

Here's where I am stuck. To configure LDAP to use Azure AD, I can follow this guide: [Implement LDAP authentication with Azure AD](https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/apache-cassandra-ldap-authentication/). What I am confused on is how this will allow an authenticated user to get into the EC2 instance to the Cassandra shell. I presume I would need some kind of client in between that.

I am very naive to the architecture of all this.

Would very much appreciate some guidance on  whether there is a better way to achieve SSO/Oauth2 authentication to a AWS Cassandra cluster, ideally using Azure as the authenticator.